# Set Up Multi-Factor Authentication for SSH on Ubuntu 16.04, but NOT for root user

Tags: linux, ubuntu-16.04, ubuntu-18.04, google-authenticator

I followed this nice guide from digitalocean to [set up Multi-Factor Authentication for SSH on Ubuntu 16.04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-multi-factor-authentication-for-ssh-on-ubuntu-16-04) Server (No UI),

after this every user on system when the login via ssh system expects additional authentication, if 2fa is setup everything works but if it isn't setup it just fails (article did mention that if I leave `nullok` in sshd it will continue without expecting 2fa if it isn't setup, but that isn't the case.)

basically I want to setup 2fa for every interactive user on system, but I **do not** want it enabled on `root` user.

BTW I did try https://askubuntu.com/a/1051973/867525, it did work for normal user, but it didn't work for root user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on Dieskim's answer above,
This is what I did to NOT apply PAM/2fa to root user.

in /etc/ssh/sshd_config where I added `AuthenticationMethods publickey,password publickey,keyboard-interactive` conditionally,

```
UsePAM yes
# Apply following rule to everyone (*) but root user (!root)
Match user "!root,*"
    AuthenticationMethods publickey,password publickey,keyboard-interactive
Match all
```

I would like to also mention following:

Initially even after having `auth required pam_google_authenticator.so nullok` in `/etc/pam.d/sshd` root login as not working and the reason behind that was `PermitRootLogin` in sshd_config was set to `prohibit-password`, and *OpenSSH needs to allow root logins using passwords for PAM auth to work with any sort of password, including OTP.*

And as I wanted `PermitRootLogin` to `no` the above `Match user` solution above works well.

Another thing about `auth required pam_google_authenticator.so nullok`, here it is thought that `nullok` means if 2fa is not configured for a user, user will still be allowed to login, but that is not the case with latest versions of `libpam-google-authenticator`

```
# Standard Un*x password updating.
@include common-password
auth required pam_google_authenticator.so nullok
```

EDIT:
Following statement is not true (Removed it from answer above), do not add `auth required pam_permit.so` in sshd file when you are enabling AuthenticationMethods optionally.

> it is important to add `auth required pam_permit.so` as last line to `/etc/pam.d/sshd`

Also test that any of your user is not able to login with out any credentials.

Answer (score 1):

Once you have Google Two Factor setup for SSH on Ubuntu it will be required for all users who are using "password authentication", but you can have Key-Based Authentication take priority (happen before password authentication. You can set that up for users who you do not want 2 factor for - root in your case

You can go ahead and simply specified that key-based authentication be disabled for all users with the following in the sshd_config file:

```
PubkeyAuthentication no
```

And only enabled for specific users via - root in your case

```
Match User root
    PubkeyAuthentication yes
```

As an added security tip you can allow only specific users with

```
AllowUsers <username> <username2>
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try this, 

I figured this when I read this `OpenSSH needs to allow root logins using passwords for PAM auth to work with any sort of password, including OTP.`

Thus cause of my problem was `PermitRootLogin` was set to `prohibit-password` when I set to `yes` it started working.

But I really want it to be like 
`PermitRootLogin` should be set to `prohibit-password` and root should  not be enabled for 2FA at all... this requirement doesn't seems obvious but for my case it is making sense.

Comment: For Security I would suggest using `PermitRootLogin no`

Comment: Yes, that's true but I use an third party application that provisions my servers and helps maintain the same, it needs root access via ssh.

Comment: Ok than just use Key-Based Authentication for root

Comment: Basically your Answer gave me the right approach to deal with this, I will post the solution here soon. Thanks.